# JScolor action during color change

Tags: jscolor

I am using jscolor and I want to change the body background accoring to the selected color during color selection. What part of jscolor should I edit?

Answer (score 0):

http://jscolor.com/try.php

8. Onchange event

use the following code you can change body background color.

```
<p>Change background: 
     <input class="color"
    onchange="document.getElementsByTagName('BODY')[0].style.backgroundColor = '#'+this.color">
</p>
```